# What is the correct way to write the statement "Employed from September till date"?

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

I want to add the following statement in an email:

> This is being written to confirm that Mr. XYZ has been employed in our organization from September 2013 till date.

The "till date" part sounds incorrect to me. Is there any alternate term I can use that has the same meaning?

Comment: "employed... since September 2014."

Comment: I would agree with @Mitch, except that his version implies Mr XYZ is a time traveller.  *Has been since September 2013* states explicitly that he still is.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm just being hopeful.

Answer (score 12):

The expression *"to date"* means *"until the present"*, although I wouldn't use it in this context; *"till date"* appears to be Indian English for *"until the present"*, and is incorrect outside of India. I don't believe anybody uses *"until date"* in this context.

I would say *"until now"* or *"until the present"*.

Comment: [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/date) **to date** (Indian also **till date**) - *until now*.

Comment: In the US, *until now* might be taken to mean he has just been let go. I agree with *to date*. Also *to the present* is also frequently found.

Comment: You're right about *until now*: *was employed until now* certainly implies that he has been let go; *has been employed until now,* less so.  In the US, you could use *through the present* to make it absolutely clear the employ is still with you, but I don't think *through* is used in this way in the UK.

Comment: Now we'll soon see "uptil" -- also invented in India, I guess!

Comment: will to-date work both side, inside and outside of India? I am using it on my portfolio website. thanks @Peter for answer.

Answer (score 1):

In British English we would say, '... until the 17th of January.' We wouldn't use till, but I understand US English does allow till in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . If I had to rewrite the above statement in British English and considering that the employee is currently employed in the organization,will this statement be grammatically correct :  This is being written to confirm that Mr.XYZ has been employed in our organization from September 2014 until date.

Comment: If you meant 'is still employed' then you should write 'until now' as 'until date' is incorrect.

Comment: @Real Chembil: Peter Shor's answer notwithstanding, I would definitely use **to date** rather than **until now** in your specific context. But in practice I probably wouldn't use *either* - I'd just write/say ***since** September 2013*.

Comment: I'd possibly write *since September* as well, but never *to date* as it just makes no sense in this context. I am prepared to believe it does in the US, but certainly not here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I am going with "since September".

Comment: I have never heard till used this way in the US or Canada. As university educated US English speaker I would disagree that US English allows till in this context.

Answer (score 1):

"Till date" has gained currency in India, but although I live in India and work as an editor, it doesn't sound right. It sounds like a term from a farmer's diary, where he's got a day kept aside to till his land.

Answer (score -2):

'Till date' is certainly used very frequently in India which is where I live. It means 'till today' or 'uptil now'. Not many here would feel it to be wrong. Those who do will be those who have had a thorough grounding in British or American standard usageGiven that a pretty huge population in India uses the term for communication with one another, I think it is about time that English users from other countries recognise that there exists an unwritten Indian English Standard, and it would be better to stop nitpickicking because it does not conform to their Standard. From the communicative point of view I'm quite sure the American or British reader knows what is meant from the context.

Comment: This is more of a rant than a real answer; moreover, it doesn't add any new information that hasn't already been given in previous answers.

Comment: Dear Janus, It does add new meanings of 'till date' viz. 'till today' and 'uptil now'. It also informs readers that the high-handedness of those English users who feel that their own standard is the right ones is resented by many Indian English users.

Comment: 1) There is no such word as _uptil_. It is _up till_ or _up ’til_ or _up until_. 2) The meaning of _till date_ as ‘until the present’ is already given in Peter’s answer. 3) The second part of your comment is what makes this a rant, not an answer. Rants are not accepted as questions or answers on ELU (or any other SE site).